# Submitting form through Ajax not working, data are null in Spring controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

When I submit my simple form using ajax call 'POST' to my DB, it saving null values to my DB. Im using Spring boot, Spring Data, PostgreSQL. Im trying to fix this for hours but cant find anything. Whats wrong with my code?

..............................................................................................................................................................

**Model:**

```
package english.chat.app.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

@Id @GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;

protected User(){};
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package english.chat.app.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import english.chat.app.model.User;
import english.chat.app.services.UserService;

@RestController
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/save", 
headers="Accept=application/json")
public void registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    userService.registerUser(user);
}

}
```

**Repository:**

```
package english.chat.app.repo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import english.chat.app.model.User;

public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My App</title>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit" id="butt">Create</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#form").submit(function (event) {

    //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
    event.preventDefault();

    fire_ajax_submit();

});

});

function fire_ajax_submit() {

var search = {};
search["password"] = $("#password").val();
search["email"] = $("#email").val();

$("#butt").prop("disabled", true);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/save",
    data: JSON.stringify(search),
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (e) {
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not selecting the dom elements correctly, #password means you are selection an element with id password , same for #email so update your html accordingly and you should be able to persist your user.

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
```